# VB6 Variant Type to .NET Type

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb6, interop, com-interop

I have some VB6 code that can't be modified easily that looks like this:

```
Dim cCount as Long
Dim rCount as Long
Dim result()

Set mx = CreateObject("Component.Class")
Dim rtn = mx.GetList(rCount,cCount,result)
```

The method it calls is currently a VB6 component that we've migrated to .NET with one issue. We're not sure what type the result() is looking for since it's a variant type. We've tried object, object[], object[][], string, string[], etc, none of which have worked.

Here's an example:

```
public bool GetList(ref long rCount, ref long cCount, ref object result)
{
  ...
}
```

I've even tried setting the third param to VariantWrapper since it will add ByRef as necessary:

```
public bool GetList(ref long rCount, ref long cCount, VariantWrapper result)
{
  ...
}
```

Any ideas what I can set the incoming result to be so that I don't have an unhandled exception?

I've created a test Interface (for COM), test Class, and test VB6 app to ensure it was an issue with the Variant. So, it's defined like so:

.NET Interface:

```
[DispId(1)]
[ComVisible(true)]
string Test(ref object[] value);
```

VB 6 method:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Set mx = CreateObject("Component.Class")
    Dim result()
    MsgBox mx.Test(result)
End Sub
```

Same issue as described above. In VB6, it just throws me out. If I compile and run it, I get a generic .NET exception and it throws me out.

Comment: You can see how `result()` is declared and passed, but not how it is used after `GetList` returns?

Comment: So as is, when the Variant() type is assigned to result and passes into GetList, .NET bombs out giving an error.

Comment: Adding VariantWrapper gives me an Error 5 Illegal procedure call.

Comment: Take a look at reflection in .NET to do what used to be done using late binding in VB6.

Comment: I've submitted my issue to the VB team. Last I knew, they thought what I'm doing should work. So I submitted a full project to them. I'll post back their response here.

Answer (score 4):

Your C# declaration is wrong.  A VB6 "Long" is 32-bits for historical reasons.  That's an int on the C# side.  With the stack frame wrong, you have no odds of getting the "result" argument passed correctly.

It ought to be a SafeArray of Variants, object[] in C#.

Comment: I've switched it to 

bool GetList(ref int rCount, ref int cCount, ref object[] result);

and it still doesn't work. I get a .NET Exception right away.

Comment: Please don't make me guess at the exception.

Comment: Hans, the exception that is thrown is "Visual Basic has generated an exception..." It only happens with the result Variant() type. I created a new .NET method to test (below is my signature form the Interface): string Test(ref object[] value); Then, I created a test VB6 app like so: Private Sub Command1_Click() Set mx = CreateObject("Component.Class") Dim result() MsgBox mx.Test(result) End Sub Same issue as described above. As I originally described, it doesn't like the Variant type.

Comment: It's going to take me a while to jumpstart that old machine.  Bleh.  I'd recommend a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint on the `mx.GetList(rCount,cCount,result)` line. Once hit, add a "quick watch" expression of `mx.GetList(rCount,cCount,result)`. The toolwindow should show you what the resulting runtime-type is. Most likely it is a "comresult" and will not provide much information, but it may provide a hint to the return type.

Comment: I've modified the code so that as soon as it hits the method, it returns a true boolean value. If I switch the result variable to a different type and test it in a quick VB6 test app, it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `ref` keyword may be causing some trouble here. The types have to match exactly for that to work.

However, if your method simply accepts a reference to any `object` by *value*, (instead of by `ref`), it can get passed anything, since everything derives from `object` in .NET.

How well this translates to VB6/COM interop, I don't know. But it seems that this is at least worth a shot:

**C# code**:

```
public string GetTypeName(object value)
{
    return value.GetType().FullName;
}
```

**VB6 code**:

```
Set mx = CreateObject("Component.Class")
Dim result()

MsgBox mx.GetTypeName(result)
```

Does that give you anything?

---

Here's an idea. I could be dead wrong here -- I've not much experience in migrating VB6 apps to .NET -- but it seems to me that if you can get as far as (the C# equivalent of) this line...

```
Set mx = CreateObject("Component.Class")
```

...then you're golden. You can use reflection to figure out what parameters the `GetList` method wants.

First get the `System.Type` object representing the type of `mx`:

```
Type mxType = mx.GetType();
```

Then find the `GetList` method(s) for that type:

```
MethodInfo[] getListMethods = mxType.GetMember("GetList")
    .OfType<MethodInfo>()
    .Where(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 3)
    .ToArray();
```

This will give you a `MethodInfo[]` array of all the public overloads of `GetList` taking 3 parameters. From here the possible types of `result` will be:

```
Type[] possibleResultTypes = getListMethods
    .Select(m => m.GetParameters()[2].ParameterType)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: That's not going to work because the VB6 app is passing into C#. It's not a question as to what types I need to use in VB6 as it is what type to set the COM method in C#. The VB6 type is of Variant(). The C# type should be object[] or VariantWrapper neither of which work.

Comment: @Jason: I think I'm confused. Are you saying it's your VB6 code that's throwing the exception? And you simply want to figure out how to define your C# method so that you can call it from VB6? Or is that backwards?

Comment: I want to figure out how to define my C# method so I can call it from VB6. However, VB6 isn't throwing the exception, it's .NET. The call goes to the class library in Interop, but because it's a .NET assembly, .NET generates the exception.

Comment: @Jason: I posted another idea. Let me know if that works/accomplishes anything for you. I probably shouldn't even be offering me help as I know next to nothing about VB6 or COM interop, but I'm intrigued by the problem so I'm just throwing my thoughts out there.

Answer (score 0):

I know only how it's used in .Net where you pass a reference to a `Variant` like this:

```
 int port = 2;
 object pvPort = new System.Runtime.InteropServices.VariantWrapper(port);
 gimp.SetPort(ref pvPort);
```

After this, put a breakpoint and check the variant type if you're not sure about it.

The main thing is using `VariantWrapper` so the dll understands.